# Container height be small as possible, but if the inner content is greater than screen, then the inner content be scrollable

Tags: flutter

I have this code in flutter:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const Header(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Column(children: [Text("Text1"), Spacer(), Text("Text2")]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I want the following: if the red container height is 100, and the blue container height is 200, than the yellow container height should be 300. This is okay now. But, if the blue container height is 2000, and overflows from screen, then I want to be the blue container scrollable.

Important!!!!
The red container height is not always 100, it depends.
The red container should always be at the top of the page, but be in the scaffold body.

I tried the SingleChildScrollView, like in example, but it does not work. I'm searching a solution for long days, I'm really hopeless now.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ok, look at the following code:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text("Text1"),
                        Text("We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services. We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services.We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services.We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services. We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services.We use cookies to personalise content, analyse our traffic and to provide social media or advertising features (when required). We also share information about your use of our site with our social media and analytics partners who may combine it with other information that you’ve provided to them or that they’ve collected from your use of their services."),
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i have placed a very very long text, it was the nearest for me to get *cookies usage alert, don't care.*

long text to show you how the screen responds when the text overflows its size.

here is the result as a pic:

[image]

notice: in your question's code, there is a `spacer` widget in the column and all is wrapped with a `scroll view`.

**you can't put a spacer inside scroll view, spacer want and will allocated any available space while single child scroll view offers infinity of space.** (illogical) and will produce unbounded height exception. didn't it?

hope it helps you.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I searched for, thank you very much!! the Spacer widget was for the demo purpose only, makes totally sense what you said.

Comment: sorry, I forgot something. the yellow container now is always fills the whole page. But for example, if the red container height is 100, and the blue container height is 200, then I want to be the yellow container height 300.